A question on Aristotle’s arguments contra Melissus and Parmenides in Physics
In Book I Part 3 of Aristotle’s Physics, he says in response to Melissus’ argument that being is one

”If, then, we approach the thesis in this way it seems impossible for all things to be one. Further, the arguments they use to prove their position are not difficult to expose. For both of them reason contentiously-I mean both Melissus and Parmenides. [Their premisses are false and their conclusions do not follow. Or rather the argument of Melissus is gross and palpable and offers no difficulty at all: admit one ridiculous proposition and the rest follows-a simple enough proceeding.] The fallacy of Melissus is obvious. For he supposes that the assumption 'what has come into being always has a beginning' justifies the assumption 'what has not come into being has no beginning'. Then this also is absurd, that in every case there should be a beginning of the thing-not of the time and not only in the case of coming to be in the full sense but also in the case of coming to have a quality-as if change never took place suddenly. Again, does it follow that Being, if one, is motionless? Why should it not move, the whole of it within itself, as parts of it do which are unities, e.g. this water? Again, why is qualitative change impossible? But, further, Being cannot be one in form, though it may be in what it is made of. (Even some of the physicists hold it to be one in the latter way, though not in the former.) Man obviously differs from horse in form, and contraries from each other.”

In response to Parmenides he says,

”If, then, 'substance' is not attributed to anything, but other things are attributed to it, how does 'substance' mean what is rather than what is not? For suppose that 'substance' is also 'white'. Since the definition of the latter is different (for being cannot even be attributed to white, as nothing is which is not 'substance'), it follows that 'white' is not-being--and that not in the sense of a particular not-being, but in the sense that it is not at all. Hence 'substance' is not; for it is true to say that it is white, which we found to mean not-being. If to avoid this we say that even 'white' means substance, it follows that 'being' has more than one meaning.”

I’ll summarize how I understand these passages, and am basically asking if my understanding is correct:

Aristotle is pointing out that for Melissus, clearly it doesn’t follow that what doesn’t come into being has no beginning from that what comes into being has a beginning. However, aside from that part, I’m confused. Is he saying that since things can change/acquire new properties/qualities suddenly, it cannot be that reality has to be a motionless unity?
With respect to Parmenides, I think he’s saying that if everything is one, then since any attribution would have to be made to that unity, if the thing attributed has a different definition, then we are essentially attributing non-being to being, as something which doesn’t exist on this account, like white, would be attributed of the unified substance. Is that even close?

I can’t quite tell what his arguments are, and have been struggling with these specific passages from the beginning of the Physics for a couple of days now. If anyone could help to clarify the context of these arguments, as well as the arguments themselves, that would be much appreciated.

Melissus posits qualitative change of being is impossible thus being's motion as an exemplified quality of the said being as posited by Aristotle must also be impossible which is absurd per Aristotle. As against Parmenides, being a positivist, Aristotle exposed the contradiction via the example of 'white' that either substance has more than one meaning or white as being-there or being-here is not-being in the sense of not at all, not a particular this or that not-being or being-not. Yet Heidegger's claim let beings be contextualized the being's reified there with a glimpse of openness...
